# How to request data from an API using AJAX.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I want to make a post request to an API (http://nairabox.com/food_documentation/) using Ajax but am kind of confused on how to go about it.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$.ajax({

           type: "POST",
           url: "https://mapp.nairabox.com:8443/api/v1/food/",
           dataType : "json",
           data: { case: "browse"},               
           headers: {
                 'case': 'browse'
             },
           success: function(data){
                console.log('success');

           }
  })
```

So far, it is returning no result.

What could I be getting wrong?

The API doc is here (http://nairabox.com/food_documentation/)

Comment: One thing you should try is putting in an error callback function (similar to the success one you gave) and see if it gets called. If so, log the contents of the error to see what it tells you.

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Are there any errors? Open the Network tab. Is the request being made? Is it formatted the way you expect? Does it get a response? Is the response formatted the way you expect? You have a `success` handler, but you don't have an `error` handler. Write one. See if it fires. Log it's arguments to see if they tell you what the problem is.

Comment: That api does not appear to be CORS enabled and you should be seeing a CORS error message in your browser dev tools console. The link you provided for api docs is invalid

Comment: what is browse here?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir It's a Param. It's in the doc. http://nairabox.com/food_documentation/

Comment: and how are your returning result from this url ? simply return or echo i mean in which format, because the success function will work if the data return request is also in json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you link to does **not** say to add any custom HTTP request headers.

You, however, are doing so here:

> ```
>        headers: {
>              'case': 'browse'
>          },
> ```

The `case` data belongs in the `data` and *only* in the data.

By adding the custom header, you are preventing the request from being simple and triggering a [preflight OPTIONS request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests) which the server does not accept.

Remove the above and you will get a response (and your `success` function will fire … you should probably do something with the `data` argument though)

---

Note, also, that the documentation says you should pass `latitude` and `longitude` as well as `case`.

Unless you add them, the response you get is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: Thank you @quentin. But am getting this error now `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mapp.nairabox.com:8443/api/v1/food/. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

Comment: @JackFrank — I can't reproduce that problem after making the modifications I proposed here: https://jsbin.com/wizuqununi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This is my code now:   `$.ajax({

           type: "POST",
           url: "https://mapp.nairabox.com:8443/api/v1/food/",
           dataType : "json",
           data: { case: "browse"},               
           success: function(data){
                console.log('success');
            
           }
  })` But now returning: `POST https://mapp.nairabox.com:8443/api/v1/food/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Comment: @JackFrank – It works fine when I test it. You appear to have a network connection issue now. That isn't a programming problem any more.

Comment: Is it returning any result? @Quentin

Comment: What could be the cause of the network connection issue?

Comment: Fault at your ISP. DNS server failure. An undersea cable being damaged. The API noticing unusual activity from your IP and applying an automatic ban. Rain. Etc.

Comment: Oh, I see now. It's actually working now under a different connection. I do appreciate your help.